# FastCGI Error Access to the script denied

Tags: debian, fastcgi

I have a Debian Squeeze server running nginx + php-fpm + fastcgi. I have a typo3 installation on this server which runs well.

No I installed OTRS and I get an error that I do not understand:

> 2012/06/25 15:35:38 [error] 16510#0: *34 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "Access to the script '/opt/otrs/bin/fcgi-bin/index.pl' has been
>   denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header
>   from upstream, client: ..., server: support.....com, request: "GET
>   /otrs/index.pl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
>   "support.....com", referrer: "http://support.....com/"

Why do I get this error? The otrs directory is writable for the webserver, so this is not the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem with index.html files which is how I got here from Google.  Among other problems, switching from spawn to php-fpm gave most of my domains "Access denied" errors.  I got the same "see security.limit_extensions" in my error.log.  The affected index.html files didn't have any PHP code either, but I assume NginX still tried to execute them through php-fpm, thus throwing the errors.  I'm using CentOS:

1. Edit `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
2. Uncomment this line, by default .htm and .html are blocked:

`security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html .htm`

3. `service php-fpm restart`

Answer (score 1):

OTRS is written in Perl, so you cannot run it through PHP-FPM. That's why you get this error. I suggest reading [this article](http://supportex.net/2011/11/migrating-otrs-apache-nginx/) for more information about running OTRS with nginx.

Comment: no, fastcgi is actually running on port 9000 I forgot to mention that. But thanks for the article I go throug it

Comment: Would you please provide server configuration for your OTRS virtual host.

Comment: the vhost config is quite the same as in your linked article

Comment: That's not possible - the article uses UNIX socket for communication, while you're obviously using TCP on port 9000. Look, the problem is that a PHP FastCGI manager is listening on port 9000 instead of Perl FastCGI manager.

Comment: Yes your, right. I will check this.

Answer (score -1):

You may try to add to you site's nginx conf file the following sentence in location /:
        index index.php index.html;

Comment: I don't think setting an index will fix this problem